# Ncurses: Dialog box background color be changed?

Tags: linux, dialog, ncurses

I am working on Linux Operating System. I want to display a dialog box on an item selection from a drop down menu implemented in ncurses, but the problem is that the dialog box fills up the screen with blue background and further nothing can be done.So, is there a way to display ncurses dialog box inside current window preserving existing ncurses components?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the relevant sections of the code you're working on? Are you using ncurses in C or another language?

Comment: I am using ncurses in C.I am using following system call to display dialog box on a menu item selection

        system("dialog --backtitle "Configuration -> View" --title     "Active configuration" --inputbox "Write File name to view:" 10 50");

I want the dialog box not to cover whole screen hiding other components behind the blue background.I just want it to appear on the current screen or window.

Comment: can you post the code snippet where you have created the dialog box..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use [CDK (Curses development kit)](http://invisible-island.net/cdk/) to the create dialog box. It provides many other widgets that you can use such as,

```
Alphalist
Button
Buttonbox
Calendar
Entry Field
File Viewer
Floating Scale
Floating Slider
Graph
Histogram etc...
```

see [this](http://invisible-island.net/cdk/manpage/cdk.3.html)